# Two different types of user with different username field types

Tags: django, django-models

Default User Model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/avatar', null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    object = managers.UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

Employer model:

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    fax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    economic_code = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    national_id = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

Employee model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    national_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    personnel_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    eligible_leave = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    sick_leave_per_month = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False, blank=False)
    rfid_card_code = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
```

I want the employer to be authenticated by email and the employee by national code (username filed). How?

Comment: I think you need to write your own authentication backend (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend).  You could identify by regural expression if the input is an email or national code and authenticate it using the Employer model or Employee model.

Comment: Thanks, but the username is a field of the User model and two different values can not be considered for it.

Answer (score 1):

you need a custom authentication backend. let's name it `backends.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class EmployeeAuthentication(ModelBackend):
    """
    Employee Backend
    
    Allows a user to sign in using national_id and password.
    """
    
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        national_id = kwargs.get('username')
        password = kwargs.get('password')
        try:
            employee = Employee.objects.get(national_id=national_id)
            if employee.user.check_password(password) is True:
                return employee.user
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            pass
            

class EmployerAuthentication(ModelBackend):
    """
    Employer Backend
    
    Allows a user to sign in using email and password.
    """
    
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        email = kwargs.get('username')
        password = kwargs.get('password')
        try:
            employer = Employer.objects.get(email=email)
            if employer.user.check_password(password) is True:
                return employer.user
        except Employer.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

and in `settings.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'app.backends.EmployerAuthentication',
    'app.backends.EmployeeAuthentication',
]
```

Comment: tnx, If the user model does not have a username field, then how can the employer and employee model be created and authenticated?

Comment: If you don’t want to use django auth user model at all, then you need to implement the methods needed in your use case from  `ModelBackend` in your custom authentication class and of course remove the inheritance from your class. For example, if you don’t need built-in permissions or groups then you just need the `get_user` method.

Comment: Is it possible to implement a simple example?